# Compiling with APR. Error msg: "no decision has been made on APR_PATH_MAX for your platform"

Tags: c, apr

I recently downloaded APR and successfully built it on my machine (Ubuntu 12.0.4).
I included /path/to/apr_file_info.h to my project, and when I attempted to compile, I got the following error message:

`no decision has been made on APR_PATH_MAX for your platform`

Upon investigating the header file (apr.h), I found that the following directives are responsible:

```
#if defined(PATH_MAX)
#define APR_PATH_MAX       PATH_MAX
#elif defined(_POSIX_PATH_MAX)
#define APR_PATH_MAX       _POSIX_PATH_MAX
#else
#error no decision has been made on APR_PATH_MAX for your platform
#endif
```

The (naive?) solution would be to define these variables - but I am not sure if there would be any nasty effects for using the wrong size - and I am not sure the correct size to define for the compiler directive.

Why is ./configure not correctly determining my platform (Ubuntu 12.0.4), and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, `PATH_MAX` should be defined in `<linux/limits.h>`. Include it before APR and it should solve your issue:

```
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <path/to/apr_file_info.h>
```

Note that including the standard header `<limits.h>` header should also include `<linux/limits.h>` or the relevant header on POSIX systems.

The equivalent on Windows would be `MAX_PATH`, defined in `<windef.h>` if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem recently. Surprised that the APR header which requires its use on Linux doesn't include the linux/limits.h directly if that is a dependency. Good programming practice surely?

Answer (score 0):

Defining symbol `_XOPEN_SOURCE` might solve this, eg `CPPFLAGS='-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`

Mind you, some programs don't honor CPPFLAGS so you have to add it to CFLAGS; tomcat-native is an example for this: when compiling it you can edit file `native/scripts/build/rules.mk`:

```
- COMPILE      = $(CC) $(CFLAGS)
+ COMPILE      = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
```